# Recover by breaking constraint in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, autolayout

Recently I discovered that when I run my app on iOS 7 devices the compiler returns an error. This doesn't happen with devices running iOS 8.

I can somehow understand that it's a `NSLayoutConstraints` problem. I don't know what is making it happen. I need to fix it without disabling the AutoLayout feature.

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7be4c240 V:[UIView:0x7be31100]-(11)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7be2f2c0 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-05-02 19:41:28.652 LM[27669:607] -[<CALayer: 0x7bfcf010> display]: Ignoring bogus layer size (99999.000000, 99999.000000)
2015-05-02 19:41:28.681 LM[27669:607] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf1d4b0 V:|-(14)-[UIView:0x7bf1a2c0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7bf1a220 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf1d510 V:[UIView:0x7bf1a2c0]-(11)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7bf1a220 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x81082660 h=--& v=--& V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7bf1a220(1)]>"
)
```

Update:

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bac9bf0 V:[UILabel:0x7bac8c00]-(65)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7bac6f60 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-05-03 00:21:03.508 MesProject[27971:607] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bac9c20 V:|-(54)-[UILabel:0x7bac8c00]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7bac6f60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bad4010 V:[UIImageView:0x7bac6490]-(56)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7bac6f60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bac88f0 V:[UILabel:0x7bac8c00]-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7bac6490]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bac6180 V:[UIView:0x7bac6f60]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7bac4f20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bac61e0 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7bac6f60]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7bac4f20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bac9a70 V:|-(14)-[UIView:0x7bac4f20]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7bac9e80 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bac9ad0 V:[UIView:0x7bac4f20]-(11)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7bac9e80 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7ed4a170 h=-&- v=-&- UITableViewCellContentView:0x7bac9e80.height == UITableViewCellScrollView:0x7bacb240.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7ed4a7f0 h=-&- v=-&- UITableViewCellScrollView:0x7bacb240.height == MesProject.CardCell:0x7bac9cf0.height>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7ed40a00 h=-&- v=--& V:[MesProject.CardCell:0x7bac9cf0(1)]>"
)
```

This error start to occur when I'm supporting IOS7 with row height and dynamic .

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 280
}
```

I've custom cell called `CardCell`:

```
class CardCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var text1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var sharefb: UIButton!

}
```

Is it possible to make the view and `UITextLabel` dynamic?

Comment: I don't know anything apart from my given answer. Since it does not fix it, i am gonna delete it and hope, someone will be able to help you!

Comment: You did what you can !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` is available in iOS 8;
- In iOS 7 you have to deal with the delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Implement this code:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        //here fix, in your case depend on your model
        // -> you manage manually not as magic as UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        return 100
    }
```

Please note that iOS 8 brought a lot of changes, such and managing older versions of iOS is a bit more painful.

Comment: Well lets say i have UILabel In the cell , how I'm gonna deal with to take the size to be dynamic, I've google the problem but its only answered using objective-c which is different than swift !

Comment: Please add more details (code, print screen) so that you will have better answer. Right now, I advise creating custum tableviewCells. Then depending on your data use tableviewcell1 or tableviewcell2 as an example. It depends on your needs.